# In express-gateway i want to log consumerid, I get the example ${req.ip} works fine but how do i reference the eg specific elements like consumerId?

Tags: logging, express-gateway

How do I reference consumerId in order to log in express-gateway - are the eg- specific 'elements' documented anywhere?

```
mytest:
 apiEndpoints:
  - test
 policies:
  - log:
     action:
       message: ${req.consumerId} ${req.ip} ${req.method} ${req.originalUrl}
  - key-auth:
  - proxy:
     action:
      serviceEndpoint: testscore
      changeOrigin: true
      stripPath: true
```

gets me a Null response

Comment: can no-one explain how I reference these elements - I cant get the answer below to work!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could get the consumer id using:
${egContext.consumer.id}
Note that it is available only after authorization policy like: oauth2

Answer (score 0):

They are all put in the `egContext` bag object.

`req.egContext.consumerId`

Comment: ${req.egContext.consumerId} returned an undefined as well?